# Disable sbt-revolver for all but one module

Tags: sbt, sbt-revolver

I have a multi-module sbt project comprised of the following modules:

```
> projects
[info] In file:/Users/me/workspace/my/project/
[info]     backend
[info]   * myproject
[info]     rest
[info]     root
```

I'd like to have [sbt-revolver](https://github.com/spray/sbt-revolver) only active on the `rest` project where my REST api code resides. This way I don't have to switch into the `rest` project in order to execute `re-start`, but rather I can execute it from the default parent project and `rest` will be the only that re-start is executed on.

How do I disable `sbt-revolver` on all projects except `rest`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried many ways and ended up with: add:

```
.disablePlugins(RevolverPlugin)
```

to projects you don't want to start.
and use:

```
addCommandAlias("mycommand", "subproject/re-start")
```

to redirect you command.

hope can help you.